# How does a javascript array work whilst pushing new elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tested this code in Chrome / Firefox :

```
console.time('simple push');
var arr0 = [];
for(var i =0; i < 1000000; i++){
    arr0.push(i);
}
console.timeEnd('simple push');
console.time('set length and push');
var arr1 = [];
arr1.length=1000000;
for(var j =0; j < 1000000; j++){
    arr1[j]=j;
}
console.timeEnd('set length and push');
console.time('new Array push');
var arr2 = new Array(1000000);
for(var k =0; k < 1000000; k++){
    arr2[k]=k;
}
console.timeEnd('new Array push');
```

## Chrome 13 Result

simple push:59ms
set length and push:192ms
new Array push:187ms

## Firefox 4 Result

simple push:76ms
set length and push:44ms
new Array push:40ms

## My doubt

So `new Array` operation is definitely the slowest, but I wanna know why?
Why set length behaves different in Chrome and Firefox, it seems preallocated memory doesn't works well in Chrome?

## Update

I updated Chrome and FF results.

Comment: You can see in the [specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.4.2.2) what `new Array(len)` is supposed to do.

Comment: Here is a link to the tests: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Vwu4V/ (which users can test in their own browsers)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Vwu4V/2/ without the size specification, flips the results

Comment: @simon -- you might want to add it to your question somewhere.

Comment: Fixed jsperf testcases to use assignment instead of push: http://jsperf.com/array-push-comparision . All methods are equally fast in FF6.

Comment: @simon I see you fixed the code, but the question doesn't make any sense anymore now that the test cases don't show any differences.

Answer (score 6):

Why is the new Array(N) the slowest?

```
console.log(arr0.length);
console.log(arr1.length);
console.log(arr2.length);

1000000
1000000
2000000
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have been already made aware of, your testcases were flawed. [Here is a jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/array-push-comparision) case which uses assignment in all methods.

The speed is the same for all of them in Firefox 6 (~50,000 op/s). In Chrome 13 however, setting the array length beforehand results in a huge speed improvement (~80,000 op/s vs. ~400.000 op/s). To find the reason for that, one would have to have a look at the source code of Chrome's JavaScript engine.

You asked what happens on `.push()` and `new Array`. The specification describes was *should* happen:

> #### [15.4.2.2   new Array (len)](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.4.2.2)
>
> The [[Prototype]] internal property of the newly constructed object is set to the original Array prototype object, the one that is the initial value of **Array.prototype** ([15.4.3.](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.4.3.1)1). The [[Class]] internal property of the newly constructed object is set to "**Array**". The [[Extensible]] internal property of the newly constructed object is set to **true**.
>
> If the argument *len* is a Number and `ToUint32(len)` is equal to *len*, then the length property of the newly constructed object is set to `ToUint32(len)`. If the argument *len* is a Number and `ToUint32(len)` is not equal to *len*, a **RangeError** exception is thrown.
>
> If the argument *len* is not a Number, then the length property of the newly constructed object is set to 1 and the 0 property of the newly constructed object is set to *len* with attributes {[[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: true, [[Configurable]]: true}..
>
> #### [15.4.4.7   Array.prototype.push ( [ item1 [ , item2 [ , … ] ] ] )](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.4.3.1)
>
> The arguments are appended to the end of the array, in the order in which they appear. The new length of the array is returned as the result of the call.
>
> When the push method is called with zero or more arguments item1, item2, etc., the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let *O* be the result of calling ToObject passing the this value as the argument.
> 2. Let *lenVal* be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of *O* with argument "**length**".
> 3. Let *n* be ToUint32(*lenVal*).
> 4. Let *items* be an internal List whose elements are, in left to right order, the arguments that were passed to this function invocation.
> 5. Repeat, while *items* is not empty
>
>    1. Remove the first element from *items* and let *E* be the value of the element.
>    2. Call the [[Put]] internal method of *O* with arguments ToString(*n*), *E*, and **true**.
>    3. Increase *n* by 1.
> 6. Call the [[Put]] internal method of O with arguments "**length**", *n*, and **true**.
> 7. Return *n*.

That said, the implementation can be different. As you saw from the difference in Firefox and Chrome, Chrome seems to optimize the array structure internally.

Comment: In Chrome 13 however, setting the array length beforehand results in a huge speed improvement?my chrome is slower when setting array's length.

Comment: @simon: Run the test cases I linked to.

Comment: @Felix: one problem is you are using N=1000, simon is using N=1000000

Comment: @Jimmy: Yes, I used a smaller number because jsperf runs each testcase several times anyway (and then takes the average I guess).

Comment: @Felix: The test is completely different. Test (1)`a=[];for(var i=0;i<N;i++)a.push(i)` versus (2)`a=[];a.length=N;for(var i=0;i<N;i++)a[i]=i;` for N = 1000 versus N=65000 on Chrome for example. (1) goes from 50% slower to 1000% faster than (2).

Comment: @Jimmy: True. In any case, both results are interesting, especially considering that it is more likely that an array has fewer than 1000 elements.

Comment: @Felix Kling -- i run your test cases and got the same result. so the speed is nearly the same in the newst browsers,am i right?